# Alignment of Single Data Bargraph in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[how to align the Bargraph Column from Left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOOUy.png)

Above image is the bargraph which i have created using HighCharts; please let me know how can i align the single data bargraph from left and reduce the column width also.

Below is the code through which i have created bargraph

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('chart', {
    chart : {
        plotBackgroundColor : null,
        plotBorderWidth : null,
        plotShadow : false
    },
    plotOptions : {
        series : {
            dataLabels : {
                enabled : true,
                formatter : function () {
                    return this.point.t;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    title : {
        text : 'Overdue Projects'
    },
    xAxis : {
        categories : ["Please Select to View data"]
    },
    yAxis : {
        title : {
            text : 'Hours'
        }
    },
    series : [{
            "type" : "column",
            "name" : "Estimated Hours",
            "data" : [2]
        }, {
            "type" : "column",
            "name" : "Consumed Hours",
            "data" : [3]
        }
    ]

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pointPlacement` and `pointPadding` for this.

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/xyh73s11/

**API references:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointPadding
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointPlacement